# Show Application's Tray Icon for all user logon

Tags: wpf, windows, server, system-tray

I have written a WPF windows tray app.
A Mutex is using  to prevent multiple instances of the same program from running. The app has been installed on a windows server.

Problem:
Windows tray Icon is visible only to the user who has run it. When another user login to server, the windows tray icon is gone.

What should I do for the windows tray to be visible to all users in different login sessions?